# When editing data in a CSV how do you exclude/only include certain columns?

Tags: python-3.x

I've got a CSV of client details for a bank project in Python 3. I've managed to create a function in which you can edit the client details but I want to exclude the last 2 columns as and and can't figure out how.

Example of CSV data:

```
first_name,last_name,title,pronouns,dob,occupation,account_balance,overdraft_limit
Garner,Coupman,Ms,Male,14/04/2022,General Manager,2200.76,2.28
Jens,Eldrid,Honorable,Male,13/11/2021,Research Associate,967.64,79.15
```

Edit function:

```
if choice == "4":
    editClient = int(input("Please enter the index number of the client you wish to edit: "))
    print("Please enter the details for each of the following: ")
    for i in range(len(existing_clients[0])):
        newDetails = input("Enter new data for " + str(existing_clients[0][i]) + ": ")
        existing_clients[editClient][i] = newDetails
    changes = input("Are you sure you'd like to make these changes? Enter Yes or No")
    if changes == ("Yes"):
        # Newline fixed the spacing issue I was having
        with open("mock_data.csv",   "w+", newline="") as file:
            reader = csv.writer(file)
            for i in range(len(existing_clients)):
                reader.writerow(existing_clients[i])
    if changes == ("No"):
        exit()
```

I've tried changing

```
for i in range(len(existing_clients[0])):
```

to

```
for i in range(len(existing_clients[0:6])):
```

and I thought this worked until I tried editing a client later the row 6.

I've also messed around a lot with

```
newDetails = input("Enter new data for " + str(existing_clients[0][i]) + ": ")
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the row with slicing and exclude the last two columns:

```
with open("mock_data.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for client in existing_clients:
        writer.writerow(client[:-2]) # exclude last two columns
```

Working example with data:

**input.csv**

```
first_name,last_name,title,pronouns,dob,occupation,account_balance,overdraft_limit
Garner,Coupman,Ms,Male,14/04/2022,General Manager,2200.76,2.28
Jens,Eldrid,Honorable,Male,13/11/2021,Research Associate,967.64,79.15
```

**test.py**

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line[:-2])
```

**output.csv**

```
first_name,last_name,title,pronouns,dob,occupation
Garner,Coupman,Ms,Male,14/04/2022,General Manager
Jens,Eldrid,Honorable,Male,13/11/2021,Research Associate
```

To select *specific* columns, you could concatenate different slices:

```
writer.writerow(line[:2] + line[5:6])  # column indexes 0, 1, and 5
```

Or use `DictReader`/`DictWriter`:

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = list(reader)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['last_name', 'occupation'], extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

**output.csv**

```
last_name,occupation
Coupman,General Manager
Eldrid,Research Associate
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't actually re-write the csv :( It runs fine but the csv file is left unchanged

Comment: @LetMeLive I've tested all this code except the first hack since you didn't give me working code to start with.  I don't know the exact content of `existing_clients` but assume it is a list of lists.  That's why I have tested examples afterward.  It's up to you to implement it in your code properly, or provide [mcve] in your question.

Comment: It is a list of lists and you were right - I was inputting it wrong as for the rest of the code I'd been reading it in differently. I still need the last two columns to exist and this method is deleting them completely, am I still implementing it incorrectly or is there a way to edit the columns I want without the last two disappearing? Cheers either way mate.

Comment: @LetMeLive My answer describes how to edit specific columns in the last couple of examples using either slicing or the dictionary reader/writers.